# why I can not use && in javascript for not blank and not space

Tags: javascript

I want to check the value is not blank or one empty space so I wrote a code

```js
var OccLocation = document.getElementById("HdnOccLocation");
if (OccLocation.value != " " && OccLocation.value != "") {
  alert("not empty");
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="HdnOccLocation" name="HdnOccLocation" value="" style="position:absolute;height:20px;color:#000000;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;width:26px;background-color:#00cccc;left:800px;font-weight:normal;top:220px;" class="textClass"
/>
```

Comment: because you should use || that is OR. You check that it is either not blank OR not space (they are alternative). With && you check that the conditions are both valid at the same time

Comment: `(OccLocation.value.trim() !== "")`

Comment: If the value is not *blank* **and** not a *single space*, then why did you alert `'empty'`?

Comment: How `alert("empty");` becomes `alert("not empty");`?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is wrong.

1. You have to use `==` instead of `!=`.
2. If you use `&&` then both condition should be `true` to return `true`, which is ultimately impossible at the same time in this case. Use `||` instead, this will be evaluated as true if any of the condition is `true`.

The condition should be:

```
if (OccLocation.value ==" " || OccLocation.value == "")
```

Even you can simplify the condition by using [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)
:

> The `trim()` method removes whitespace from both ends of a string. Whitespace in this context is all the whitespace characters (space, tab, no-break space, etc.) and all the line terminator characters (LF, CR, etc.).

Try

```
if (OccLocation.value.trim() ==  "")
```

```js
var OccLocation = document.getElementById("HdnOccLocation");

if (OccLocation.value.trim()== ""){
  alert ("empty");
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="HdnOccLocation" name="HdnOccLocation" value="" style="position:absolute;height:20px;color:#000000;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;width:26px;background-color:#00cccc;left:800px;font-weight:normal;top:220px;" class="textClass" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update your condition as below.

```
var OccLocation = document.getElementById("HdnOccLocation");
if (OccLocation.value.trim() == "") {
    alert("empty");
}
```

If you want to get alert if `OccLocation` is not empty then :

```
var OccLocation = document.getElementById("HdnOccLocation");
if (OccLocation.value.trim() != "") {
    alert("not empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking that it is not empty, then alerting that it is empty. I think you mean to check that it is empty. Change your JS to the following:

```
var OccLocation = document.getElementById("HdnOccLocation");

if (OccLocation.value === " " || OccLocation.value === "")
{
    alert ("empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs immediately, and the `value=""` sets it to empty.
Here, I set the value in the markup so it has some, thus it alerts.

```js
var OccLocation = document.getElementById("HdnOccLocation");
console.log(OccLocation.value)
if (OccLocation.value != " " && OccLocation.value != "") {
  alert("not empty");
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="HdnOccLocation" name="HdnOccLocation" value="dd" style="position:absolute;height:20px;color:#000000;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;width:26px;background-color:#00cccc;left:800px;font-weight:normal;top:220px;" class="textClass"
/>
```